# How to get the general solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Three solutions of a certain second order non-homogeneous linear differential equation are $$y_1(x)=1+xe^{x^2} , y_2(x)= (1+x)e^{x^2}-1 , y_3(x)=1+e^{x^2}$$
Which of the following are general solutions of the differential equation ?

1.$(C_1+1)y_1+(C_2-C_1)y_2-C_2y_3. $

2.$ C_1(y_1-y_2)+C_2(y_2-y_3).$

3.$ C_1(y_1-y_2)+C_2(y_2-y_3)+C_3(y_3-y_1).$

4.$C_1(y_1-y_3)+C_2(y_3-y_2)+y_1 $ ,  Where $C_1 , C_2$ and $C_3$ are arbitrary constant.

My efforts is that  ,  option third will be wrong (since the  second order differential equation is given, So in the general solution , the number of constant should be two only.)

Comment: I'd be tempted to agree with you

Comment: But what about others options, how can I check?

Comment: I would check to see whether there are (constant) values of $C_1$ and $C_2$ that allow you to recover each of $y_1,y_2,y_3$ as a solution.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: Not yet but I'm trying.

Comment: In this 2 and 4 options are only correct , 1 option is wrong ,  why I'm not getting.

Comment: Why do you think 1) is wrong?

Comment: Are you there 118413?

Comment: Sorry , I was wrong 1 and 4 are correct but why 2 is wrong ?

Comment: Here three solutions are given of second order nonhomogeneous equation means , two solution will be from complementary function i.e. $ CF = C_1y_1+C_2y_2$ and third is from particular solution $y_p$. Then general solution will be the form of $y= CF+y_p$.

Comment: I think so, in 2 there is no particular solution value ,so will be wrong.

Comment: In (2), no values of $C_1$ and $C_2$ give the solution $y_1$.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** Any linear combination of solutions of a non-homogeneous second order linear differential equation is again a solution if the sum of the coefficients is one.

**For option $\bf {(1)}$ :** If the solution is
$$(C_1+1)y_1+(C_2-C_1)y_2-C_2y_3$$Sum of coefficients is $$(C_1+1)+(C_2-C_1)-C_2=1$$Hence option $(1)$ is correct.

**For option $\bf {(2)}$ :** If the solution is
$$C_1(y_1-y_2)+C_2(y_2-y_3)=C_1y_1+(C_2-C_1)y_2-C_2y_3$$ Sum of coefficients is $$C_1+(C_2-C_1)-C_2=0$$Hence option $(2)$ is incorrect.

**For option $\bf {(3)}$ :** If the solution is
$$C_1(y_1-y_2)+C_2(y_2-y_3)+C_3(y_3-y_1)=(C_1-C_3)y_1+(C_2-C_1)y_2+(C_3-C_2)y_3$$Sum of coefficients is $$C_1-C_3+C_2-C_1+C_3-C_2=0$$Hence option $(3)$ is again incorrect.

**For option $\bf {(4)}$ :** If the solution is
$$C_1(y_1-y_3)+C_2(y_3-y_2)+y_1=(C_1+1)y_1+(-C_2)y_2+(C_2-C_1)y_3$$Sum of coefficients is $$C_1+1-C_2+C_2-C_1=1$$Hence option $(4)$ is correct.